# Dimension of a module (as vector space)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading the proof of the following  (part of a) lemma:

> Let $A$ be a K-algebra. If $A$ is finite, then any nonzero module contains a simple submodule.

The proof of this is where I am stuck:

> **Proof:**  Any submodule of minimal (finite) dimension as a K-vector space will be simple.

I have not yet familiarized myself with the use of modules that much. Could anyone explain to me

- what is the dimension of a module as a K-vector space
- why is it so obviously simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a ring then $R$ by definition acts on any $R$-module. If $S\subseteq R$ is a subring, then $S$ also acts on these $R$-modules. In this way, any $R$-module is *also* an $S$-module, as it has an action of $S$ on it.

If $A$ is a $K$-algebra, where $K$ is a field, then $K$ acts on any $A$-module $M$. In particular this means that $M$ is a vector space over $K$. Since it's a vector space over $K$, we can speak of its dimension.

Pick any $m\in M$ nonzero and consider the $A$-submodule $Am$. Since $Am$ is a quotient module of $A$ (there is an onto map $A\to Am$ given by $a\mapsto am$), it must have dimension less than or equal to that of $A$ as a vector space over $K$. In particular, it must be finite-dimensional if $A$ is. Therefore, if $A$ as a vector space over $K$ is finite-dimensional, then any $A$-module has an $A$-submodule that is also a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$.

Thus, it makes sense to speak of an $A$-submodule of $M$ of *minimal* nonzero dimension over $K$; one must exist. If the submodule $N$ is such, then can $N$ contain a proper nonzero $A$-submodule?

Comment: I'd say $N$ can't contain a proprer nonzero $A$-submodule (say $N'$) because the dimension of $N'$ over $K$ would be less than that of $N$, contradicting its minimality. Am I right?

Comment: @gebruiker Exactly.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by quotient module. (Don't suppose it's critical, though...)

Comment: @gebruiker Have you heard of quotient groups? You've never worked with a quotient module before? There is an isomorphism theorem which says that any surjective image of a module is isomorphic to the domain's module quotiented by the kernel (*just* like with groups and rings). In any case, ignoring the word "quotient," you know $A\to Am$ is a surjective $A$-module homomorphism, so it must be a vector space homomorphism, so $Am$ has dimension $\le$ that of $A$.